# MongoDB Query SELECT one field if the other is null

Tags: mongodb

I've got a collection of documents where one field name is different, but it means the same thing.
So I want to be able to do something similar to the SQL CASE statement:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN field1 IS NULL THEN field2
         ELSE field1
```

On top of that, I need to do an aggregate:

```
db.coll.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: "fieldID",
           maxThing: { $max: { $divide: [ "fieldA", "fieldB" ] } }
           ELSE IF fieldA IS NULL
           maxThing: { $max: { $divide: [ "fieldC", "fieldD" ] } }
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Your explanation is ambiguous, please try to refactor uour query and add some code regarding your documents schema design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best to use the **[`$ifNull`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/)** operator in your aggregation pipeline:

For the first case you could use it in the **[`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline stage:

```
db.coll.aggregate([
    {
        $project:   {
            "item": 1,
            "field1": { "$ifNull": [ "$field1", "$field2" ] }   
        }
    }
])
```

As for the other case:

```
db.coll.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": "$fieldID",
            "maxThing": { 
                "$max": { 
                    "$divide": [ 
                        { "$ifNull": [ "$fieldA", "$fieldC" ] } ,
                        { "$ifNull": [ "$fieldB", "$fieldD" ] }
                    ] 
                } 
            }       
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: The {$project: { field... ifnull....}} works.  And the aggregate also works.  However, the aggregate only *half* works.  It only gives the result if one of the fields provided is null.

Comment: Looks like [**original problem**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33136093/mongodb-query-select-one-field-if-the-other-is-null) is solved isn't it? As for the above comments, that would be a **[different question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions "at Stack Exchange sites, “chameleon questions” are not quite welcome")**, consider posting it separately.

Answer (score 0):

I take it back.  It ***does*** work, using it on this simple test case, below.  But in my production case, it fails.  Something must be amiss somewhere.  I need to figure that out.

```
JSON:
{
    "id" : "Identifier A",
    "fieldA" : 1,
    "fieldB" : 2
},
{
    "id" : "Identifier B",
    "fieldC" : 3,
    "fieldD" : 4
}

QUERY:
db.test.aggregate(
    [{
        $group: {
            _id: "$id",

            maxOfDiv: {
                $max: {
                    $divide: [{
                        "$ifNull": ["$fieldA", "$fieldC"]
                    }, {
                        "$ifNull": ["$fieldB", "$fieldD"]
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }]
)
```